# IFrame opens in entire window

Tags: iframe, window

I have defined Iframe in html, from javascript i am trying to changes the url(src) of the iframe it working fine with most of the urls. But when i supposed to set an eBay item url more than once it opens in entire window,

hear is my code

```
<html>
```

function seturl(){
     var txt=document.getElementsByName("txt");
      document.getElementById('testframe').src = txt[0].value; 

   }

any solutions to avoid the opening in entaire page of eaby items url

http://cgi.ebay.com/Apple-iPad-Wi-Fi-32GB-BRAND-NEW-NO-RESERVE_W0QQitemZ220725228457QQcategoryZ171485QQcmdZViewItem

hear i given some testing url

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Some pages include some code to prevent being loaded in an iframe as part of another page.

It is usually done in an effort to prevent unauthorized use of their page through recontextualizing, as well as mitigate various security attacks.

There isn't a good way to prevent a page from unframing itself. That's usually considered to be a feature.